# Can I put Windows 7 64-bit on my computer?

Tags: 64-bit, requirements

I have a Toshiba P200-RT1 with an Intel Pentium Processor T2080 (1M Cache, 1.73 GHz, 533 MHz FSB), and Windows Vista Home Premium 32-bit installed.

Can I run Windows 7 64-bit on my computer?

Comment: As a consolation, 64bit does not provide many benefits unless you have 4gb of ram or more. With 1 or 2gb ram system, it can even waste more memory (some subsystems are loaded in both 32 and 64bits versions at the same times on x64) and be slower than windows 7 32bit.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, you can't, your CPU is not 64 bits capable, as described in [this link](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=29740&code=T2080).

Comment: Not sure who was fastest :(

Answer (score 2):

No you can't, because your processor has a 32-bit instruction set.
http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=29740

Comment: 1 min later, but good answer too, +1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to this link:
http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers-and-processors/power-architecture-processors/qoriq-platforms/t-series/qoriq-t2080-and-t2081-multicore-communications-processors:T2080#features

The T2080 has a "Hybrid 32-bit mode to support legacy software and transition to a 64-bit architecture"